# Point perl at specific freeTDS library

Tags: perl, freetds

We have multiple versions of perl and multiple versions of freeTDS compiled on the system.  Is there a way that I can tell perl exactly which freeTDS version to use, or is that somehow built in?

The 'default' version of freeTDS that gets called when I "use DBI" in my perl script points to a version that doesn't seem to actually work properly.  I've discovered this via testing with the tsql command that comes with freeTDS.  if I run it from that version, failure.  If I run from another freeTDS version we have installed, it connects just fine.

But now I don't know how to point perl at the other version of freeTDS.

Comment: Do you use freeTDS to connect to Sybase  or to MSSQL Server, or both?

Comment: Connecting to MSSQL from Linux

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link on how to specify what version of a module that you want to use: [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

Is is essentially `use module version;`

Here is a link to perlmonks where configuring freeTDS is discussed:  [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=392385)

Comment: `use module version` has nothing to do with this question; that's only about specifying the minimum version of the Perl module you're loading.

Answer (score 1):

The freeTDS library must be specified while the corresponding DBD driver (I guess [DBD::Sybase](http://p3rl.org/DBD::Sybase)) is installed/compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using [DBD::Sybase](http://search.cpan.org/~mewp/DBD-Sybase/Sybase.pm) as your driver. When building the module, one must provide two environment variables:

- `$SYBASE`: the path to the already-built FreeTDS SDK: on Linux that would be the path to a directory containing two subdirectories:

  - `include` (`.h` files)
  - `lib64` (`.a` files)
- `$FREETDS`: the path to the FreeTDS config

  - on Linux it must contain `etc\*.conf`, on Windows it must contain directly the `*.conf` files
  - IIRC, this variable isn't used until the test-phase (i.e. run-time) of DBD::Sybase